# No longer monitor SVN directories

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a working copy of an SVN repository checked out.  The directory of interest contains 10 subdirectories in the repository which were of interest, but they do not pertain to me any longer.  I now no longer need to have them in my working copy nor monitor them, but I need to add two new subdirectories to the main directory.  Something like this:

What I have:

```
DOI/
    DontCare1/
    DontCare2/
    DontCare3/
```

What I would like to see is:

```
DOI/
    NewSub1/
    NewSub2/
```

So what I did was to remove the DontCare directories from my working copy outside of SVN - using rm rather than `svn delete`.  I then add my new directories and their contents using `svn add`.  Do an `svn commit NewSub*` and all looks good.  Obviously I can commit when there are directories missing from the main DOI directory and fortunately they don't get deleted since I didn't use `svn delete`.

But, if I now do `svn status` I get all the original DontCare directories and their contents listed as missing (! in first column).

Is there any way I can ignore these DontCare directories when I do `svn status` from the main DOI directory?  Or am I simply stuck with this scenario since that's what is present in the repository.  I can easily enough do `svn status NewSub*` and avoid seeing all the other directories/files, but it might be nice to not have to track all those others.

If I continue as I have it with missing DontCare directories in the main DOI, is there any danger of inadvertently sending those deletes to the repository?  Like I said, no`svn delete` command was used - simply `rm` from the local working copy.

BTW, I'm using svn client v1.7.18 on Fedora 19.  Server version is 1.3.2. (And no, I don't manage the server version or it would have been updated long ago!)

Answer (score 1):

You can|have to read and use (better - re-create from scratch your WC) [sparse directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html)

I.e you'll

- checkout empty DOI
- update with infinity depth only needed dirs

As result you'll get clean Working copy with only needed data (no dirty `svn st` anymore) and no possibilities to make mistake and remove from repository DontCare* dirs (deleting isn't disaster, because can be undo'ed, but **Bad Thing (tm)** anyway)

<sub>PS: Subversion 1.3.*, released May 2006, at server-side is (today) just terrible nightmare!!! You have almost nothing from today's Subversion, even automatic merge-tracking</sub>

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for the info!  (And, yes, I cannot fathom why our SA isn't updating from svn 1.3.  Probably a good reason, but...)